# PowerShell - Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hi I am new developing scripts in powershell and Active Directory, I am trying to run the following .ps1

```
#! /usr/bin/pwsh

param ([String]$dns, [String]$adminUser, [String]$adminPassword, [String]$user, [String]$newPassword)

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $adminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $newPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($adminUser, $password)
$session = New-PSSession -cn $dns -Credential $credential -Authentication Negotiate
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user -Reset -NewPassword ($pass)}
```

passing the arguments like this

```
./changePasswordAD.ps1 mydns myuser mypassword userToEdit NewPassword
```

the result obtained is the following

```
Set-ADAccountPassword: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

I am grateful in advance for your contributions

Comment: Change `{Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user -Reset -NewPassword ($pass)}` to `{Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $using:user -Reset -NewPassword $using:pass}`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the issue was solved with your contributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) problem. A [`ScriptBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.1) can't directly reference variables defined in another PowerShell session. New sessions are used when remoting or relying on [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-7.1). This is hinted at by the presence and use of `New-PSSession`, `Enter-PSSession`, etc. when PSRemoting, but isn't as obvious when using jobs.

You can prefix the variable reference in the `ScriptBlock` with `$using:` like so in order to "use" the variable defined within the calling session:

```
{
  Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $using:user -Reset -NewPassword $using:pass
}
```

However, the [`using` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1#example-5-using-a-local-variable-in-a-remote-command) can't be used when running a `ScriptBlock` on the local system. Referencing a local variable *would* work fine if you executed the `ScriptBlock` locally within the same session (using the call operator `&`, `Invoke-Command` is not usually recommended for local use since it unnecessarily relies on `PSRemoting`). So what if we want it to *run anywhere*?

---

If the `ScriptBlock` needs to be able to function regardless of execution context, you can use the
`-ArgumentList` parameter of `Invoke-Command` (this also applies to cmdlets like `Start-Job` when execution would be local but within a new session) instead to pass the variables into the `ScriptBlock`:

```
Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $user, $pass {
  Param( $user, $pass )
  Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user -Reset -NewPassword $pass
}
```

I added line breaks for readability but both `ScriptBlocks` above should function as a one-liner as well.

> Note: Technically, parameters passed via `-ArgumentList` would be referenced as `$args[0]`, `$args[1]`, etc. in the order provided such as when processing raw script arguments, but as executing a `ScriptBlock` functions similarly to a script or... well, function, adding the `Param( .... )` bit will cause the arguments provided to be assigned to positional parameters defined in the `ScriptBlock`; in this case, the friendlier names `$user` and `$pass`. The `param` names do not need to be the same as the original variable names in the parent scope.